# Quasi-compactness of irreducible separated scheme locally of finite type

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes

Is an irreducible separated scheme locally of finite type necessarily quasi-compact?

Comment: No. Let $(S_0,p_0)$ be $(\mathbb{A}^2,(0,0))$. Iteratively define $S_{i+1}$ to be the blow up of $S_i$ along $p_i$ and $p_{i+1}$ to be an arbitrary point on the new exceptional divisor. You can glue all the $S_i-p_i$ into one scheme $S_{\infty}.$

Comment: @dhy what if we require the scheme to be one-dimensional?

Comment: If you require the scheme to be one-dimensional, then I think the answer should be yes, essentially because there will be a scheme parametrizing valuations on the underlying field of fractions... but I need to think a bit to make sure this can actually be made rigorous when you are not necessarily over a field.